# Sphinx_Query failed: no enabled local indexes to search

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Hi I configured sphinx search in my test server.

Now I am getting this kind of an error "Sphinx_Query failed: no enabled local indexes to search".

I am not getting why this error. Any body can help me plese.

This is my sphinx conf

```
source objectcollection
{
    type                    = mysql
    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user                = root
    sql_pass                = root
    sql_db                  = mydatabase
    sql_port                = 3306  

    sql_query                       = \
        SELECT id, id as mid  obtype_id, searchtext from tab_objectcollection;

    sql_attr_uint           = mid
    sql_attr_uint           = obtype_id
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM tab_objectcollection WHERE id=$id

}


index combinedobject
{
    source              = objectcollection
    path                = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/objectcollection
    morphology          = stem_en
    min_stemming_len    = 4
    stopwords           = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/stopwords.txt
    min_word_len        = 3
    min_prefix_len      = 3
    min_infix_len       = 0
    enable_star         = 1
    phrase_boundary = ., ?, !, U+2026 # horizontal ellipsis
    phrase_boundary_step = 100
    html_strip = 1

}


indexer
{
        # memory limit, in bytes, kiloytes (16384K) or megabytes (256M)
        # optional, default is 32M, max is 2047M, recommended is 256M to 1024M
        mem_limit = 256M

        # maximum xmlpipe2 field length, bytes
        # optional, default is 2M
        #
        max_xmlpipe2_field = 16M


        # write buffer size, bytes
        # several (currently up to 4) buffers will be allocated
        # write buffers are allocated in addition to mem_limit
        # optional, default is 1M
        #
        #write_buffer = 16M
}

searchd
{
    listen              = 3312
    max_matches         = 10000
    log                 = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd.log
    query_log           = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/query.log
    pid_file            = /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd.pid
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide also the php code where you call sphinx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you

1. Actully built the index - ie called 'indexer' program, to make the index files.
2. Started the Search Daemon - `searchd`

Comment: I've done both of these. I'm using the main-delta pattern and it searches my main index fine, but gives this error for the delta one.

Comment: This didn't help me.  See Timmmm's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I think this error means that sphinx can't find the file(s) specified by "path" in your index. In my case I had:

```
path = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/delta
```

And I had ran the `indexer` successfully (or so I thought) like this:

```
indexer delta --rotate
```

It said there were some documents collected. HOWEVER it actually created *these* files:

```
/var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/delta.new.sp?
```

And `searchd` failed to rotate the files. Thus spake the log:

```
WARNING: rotating index 'delta': rename '/var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/delta.mvp' to '/var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/delta.old.mvp' failed: No such file or directory
```

The solution was: delete those `new` files and run `indexer` without `--rotate` the first time.

The fact that `--rotate` doesn't work the first time seems like a bit of a bug to me, but I can't really be bothered to submit a bug report. It probably requires me to register or some nonsense. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: --rotate was the puppy for me. Would be nice if the docs mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

What I Understand by your question is, in the configuration file you have to mention which table or data is to be Indexed into it. Also there could be a problem with Sphinx daemon, that it is not able to create the Indexed data and write it into files. Do check with the above.
Hope to be of help somehow.

Comment: Hi Nishant database and sqls are mentioned on my sphinx.conf index. What u mean by sphinx daemon problem? can u help me

Comment: Daemon is the background process which runs actually to index all the entries of the table. Do check if the process is active there in your server (or the local system) or not. If yes, please share the sphinx configuration file.

Comment: Hi Nishant plz check. my conf file is added in my post

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with sphinx 2.0.5, it's filed here:

http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=1268

Try using a different version (I tried 2.0.6 and the problem is gone)